# React JS Toogle Class

Tags: reactjs, toggle

I have a project that I am developing with React JS. The problem is that I have a button and when I click on it, I just want the icon on the button I click to change. But the icons on all the buttons I click change. My code is below.

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
    icon: false
}
}

active = (event) => {
    this.setState({icon: !this.state.icon})           
}

.....

const menu = ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']
<div className="nav_menu">
<ul>
    {menu.map((item,index) => 
        <li key = {index}>
            <Link data-id = {index} className="inactive" to={`${match.url}`} onClick={this.active}>
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} className="icon"/>
                    </span>
                    {item}
                </span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon data-id = {index} icon={icon ? faAngleDown:faAngleRight} className="angle"/>
            </Link>
        </li>
    )}
</ul>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just one variable wouldn't suffice as you are not storing which button index has been clicked to accurately show the icon on only that button.

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
    icon: false,
    clickedIndex: -1,
}
}

active = (clickedIndex)=> (event) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({icon: !prevState.icon, clickedIndex }));          
}

.....

const menu = ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']
<div className="nav_menu">
<ul>
    {menu.map((item,index) => 
        <li key = {index}>
            <Link data-id = {index} className="inactive" to={`${match.url}`} onClick={this.active(index)}>
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} className="icon"/>
                    </span>
                    {item}
                </span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon data-id = {index} icon={(icon && index === this.state.clickedIndex) ? faAngleDown:faAngleRight} className="angle"/>
            </Link>
        </li>
    )}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample how you can select particular. live demo https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-browser-fls2w

```
export default class Abc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { icon: false };
  }
  active = item => {
    this.setState({ icon: item });
  };
  render() {
    const menu = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"];
    return (
      <div className="nav_menu">
        <ul>
          {menu.map((item, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              onClick={() => this.active(index)}
              style={{ color: this.state.icon === index ? "red" : "" }}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Likewise, when I click on any link from the list, the icons on all links change